How to solve this problem "unity android gradle build failed"?
I've been trying to build my Android app for a while and can't seem to find any solution for this problem:
Preface
The project was built on version 2021.3.22f1 and it was necessary to raise the Android API version to 34. After this upgrade, the project was assembled and we released it to the store. But a problem was discovered there in the form of crashes on devices. The problem was localized and the developers of a third-party service for collecting analytics were contacted. He advised to upgrade to Unity version 2022.3.50f1.
After the transition, the build stopped building with errors
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2022.3.50f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/OpenJDK/bin/java -classpath "/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2022.3.50f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/gradle/lib/gradle-launcher-7.5.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "bundleRelease"

Environment Variables:
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_REDBUCKET_DEV = 46b8b46515e7632fc42a504b72e05fd0
DEBUG_ENV_VAR = UnityHub
XPC_FLAGS = 0x0
__CFBundleIdentifier = com.unity3d.unityhub
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_GREENBUCKET_DEV = 3ded2a762163603391a425f688f990c8
AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_REDBUCKET_DEV = U4PSN7S7PuYVRODivvdcFwbu8R6IHGqa
COMMAND_MODE = unix2003
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_GREENBUCKET_PROD = c86fea37a9e1d3f0878b96e15b111c7c
SENTRY_ACCESS_TOKEN = 3df78d9e53f8456aa90fbae044ce1a6261421ab1d0014674bc2e933477289017
JAVA_HOME = /Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2022.3.50f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/OpenJDK
AMPLITUDE_DEPLOYMENT_KEY_RED_BUCKET_DEV = client-wbjHYrmeSR87GmWOE7LDpf7sUySOIKHm
AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_GREENBUCKET_PROD = ZpUcbAdZXJYzNSoHsAWtL_s_JppwWid9
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY = 28f3cae0b33b8b3702120c9ed1a935aa
XPC_SERVICE_NAME = application.com.unity3d.unityhub.11447275.11447284
ANDROID_NDK_ROOT = /Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2022.3.50f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/NDK
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_STAGING = 83ee04fccc67e4fcc7dd527c4c6f1e21
WOOTRIC_CLIENT_TOKEN = NPS-aa8be4c3
USER = honkhonk
MallocNanoZone = 0
LOGNAME = honkhonk
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING = 0x1F5:0x7:0x31
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_YELLOWBUCKET_DEV = 48835b4d1f5e342aefe5f016324d296a
PATH = /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
SSH_AUTH_SOCK = /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.e1gIWyZsRS/Listeners
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_YELLOWBUCKET_PROD = e03a9bbe92dc38a88cdb068d24c65b46
AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_REDBUCKET_PROD = jTIgKs5KTZOjiqEEVdZFbgo_VRhABduL
AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_YELLOWBUCKET_PROD = UYDQtPOw83dIfVy3SrW5oMyo7ru4PRkV
HOME = /Users/honkhonk
TMPDIR = /var/folders/30/z0ysz4t50yxdm_6hfm03v1bh0000gn/T/
AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_GREENBUCKET_DEV = 84H2gMm_FJzhr3mBaX1lM1JVukmCM7d9
AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_YELLOWBUCKET_DEV = wKi8foVigDditGFvmZewRFWsEbX9Y0YO
SHELL = /bin/zsh
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_REDBUCKET_PROD = ca12bb461ea96f9bdf5df4ded7d52994
AMPLITUDE_DEPLOYMENT_KEY_RED_BUCKET_PROD = client-zH8Y7OK1i331EKuG77C6UxN8ygcM6LzS
ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = undefined


stderr[

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file '/Users/honkhonk/MyWellnessStory/Library/Bee/Android/Prj/IL2CPP/Gradle/launcher/build.gradle' line: 8

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':launcher'.
> Could not find method namespace() for arguments [com.SiberianWellness.WayToWellness] on extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':launcher'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

Here is gradle
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    implementation project(':unityLibrary')
    }

android {
    namespace "com.SiberianWellness.WayToWellness"
    ndkPath "/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2022.3.50f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/NDK"

    compileSdkVersion 35
    buildToolsVersion '34.0.0'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 35
        applicationId 'com.SiberianWellness.WayToWellness'
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
        }
        versionCode 181
        versionName '3.20.5'
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress = ['.unity3d', '.ress', '.resource', '.obb', '.bundle', '.unityexp'] + unityStreamingAssets.tokenize(', ')
        ignoreAssetsPattern = "!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('/Users/honkhonk/MyWellnessStory/OtherFiles/ForAutoBuild/user.keystore')
            storePassword 'StoryWellnessMy2020'
            keyAlias 'publish'
            keyPassword 'StoryWellnessMy2020'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            jniDebuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        doNotStrip '*/armeabi-v7a/*.so'
        doNotStrip '*/arm64-v8a/*.so'
        jniLibs {
            useLegacyPackaging true
        }
    }

    bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = false
        }
        density {
            enableSplit = false
        }
        abi {
            enableSplit = true
        }
    }
}


I've been trying to search answer in Google.

`* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':launcher'.

Could not find method namespace() for arguments [com.SiberianWellness.WayToWellness] on extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension.



What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':launcher'.


compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle`

These lines exactly tells you the problem.

The minimum AGP version for building API level 34 is 8.1.1. The minimum AGP version for building API level 35 is 8.6.0
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.6.0"

And you also need to upgrade the Gradle version accordingly

Gradle 8.0 for AGP 8.1.1
Gradle 8.7 for AGP 8.6.0


Thx for help!) You saved my day

@Fandr, could you accept my answer by clicking the green tick?
